# Elastic Search: Index a File Object

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Can any one please tell me if the two below use cases can be implemented in elasticsearch..

1) index a File Object , mostly a text file

2) If above is possible, search for the pattern say "world" in hello.txt and if "world" is present in line no 10 and line no 15, in that case , elastic search should return 10 and 15 too with other informations in the response.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you can index text files using [Mapper Attachments Type Plugin
   for Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments)

> The mapper attachments plugin lets Elasticsearch index file
>   attachments in over a thousand formats (such as PPT, XLS, PDF) using
>   the Apache text extraction library [Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/).
>
> In practice, the plugin adds the `attachment` type when mapping
>   properties so that documents can be populated with file attachment
>   contents (encoded as `base64`).

2. No, you won't be able to do that. This is not mentioned anywhere in plugin page.

Comment: There might be something you can do with highlights though. Wouldn't necessarily give you the line, but it could give you the content. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments#highlighting-attachments

Comment: @fabianvf I totally agree with you, but I havent mentioned it, since OP didn't ask this.